# Trying to display the tutor names who salary is higher than the average salary

Tags: sql

What I try to do is

```
SELECT tName, avg(Tutor.salary) AS avgSalary
FROM Tutor
GROUP BY tName
HAVING Tutor.salary > avgSalary;
```

Comment: What do you get so far? Are there any errors? Your code outputs wrong data?

Comment: I got an error saying that the avgSalary is an invalid identifier on line 4

Comment: Will post an answer.

Comment: What SQL Server are you using? MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is incomplete, I assume you have columns `tName` and `salary` in table `Tutor`. What you want to do is extract the average and then compare:

```
SELECT tName, salary FROM Tutor
WHERE
salary > (SELECT avg(salary) FROM Tutor);
```

Comment: Yea the question was incomplete the whole thing really was to list all the tutor names whose salary is greater than the average salary and
show how much the salary is greater than by.